# Deploying specific TeamCity build Arifact using Build Master

Tags: buildmaster

We use Team City as our CI server and Build Master as our deployment mechanism. I have a project that builds and runs test on teamcity and creates a `release-0.0.%build.number%.zip`.

How do i instruct Build Master to get the latest `release-0.0.%build.number%.zip`?
Currently I use Create Build Artifact which collects files from a directory, but this is causing problems for us. I already have the artifact as a .zip and just want to deploy that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [TeamCity Extensions](http://inedo.com/buildmaster/extensions/teamcity)? The idea that immediately comes to mind is to use the Get TeamCity Artifact action, which has the option to use latest Build or specify a variable. This might be easiser than pulling from disk, too.

Comment: I am using the TeamCity extension, are there examples as too how to create variables for TeamCity `%build.number%`?